# how to refer a component from a package in Lightning component

Tags: lightning, managed-package

I have a managed package installed and a page from the package is displayed in our vf pages, now I need the same functionlity in lightning component, how can I refer the package in lightning and access the component in the package.
I created a component and tried to refer the managedpackage as follows.

```
<aura:component access="global">

<c:managedPackageName: ComponentNAme/>

</aura:Component>
```

It may be because of the name space differ for lightning and managed package I am lightning component not able to recognize the managedPackage as internal component.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Typically, managed components are simply referred to by their fully-qualified API name from outside their namespace.

Comment: I added the code in the question but not dispalying so I am writing it here again, <aura:Component access="global"> <c:managedPackageName:componentName /> </aura:component>

Comment: You need to use the `{}` tool in the editor to format your code.

Answer (score 1):

In Lightning, `c:` denotes the org's unmanaged metadata. When you refer to a managed component, you should *not* use `c:`, but instead use that package's namespace in the same fashion:

```
<namespace:ComponentName />
```